# SQL: Cannot convert nvarchar to numeric in complex query

Tags: sql, sql-server, geolocation

I need to get the nearest airport in my database table from the current users position. I found this formula: https://de.scribd.com/presentation/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL#page=7

So there are a few differences between the formula described in the link above and my current situation: The example was in MySQL, I'm using MS SQL (not a problem, I guess). `lat` and `lon` are considered to be database columns with `numeric` data type, but for some reason the database table was created with two corresponding columns of type `varchar`.

My problem is: When I want to use an `ORDER BY` clause, it throws `Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric`, without it, it works. I did some research on what rubbish was inserted as string and migrated it so that I just have some empty values.

I can't take all because I only need one. But if I do `TOP 1` without `ORDER BY` I don't get *any* airport rather than the nearest airport. Does anyone know how to fix the query?

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT TOP 1
  temp.Distance
FROM (
  SELECT
    (
      3956 * 2 * ASIN(
          SQRT(
              POWER(
                  SIN((53.6349994 - abs(CAST(latitude_deg AS numeric))) * pi() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(53.6349994 * pi()/180) * COS(abs(CAST(latitude_deg AS numeric)) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((10.0117336 - CAST(longitude_deg AS numeric)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) AS Distance
  FROM Airport_Airports
  WHERE
    isnumeric(longitude_deg) = 1 AND isnumeric(latitude_deg) = 1 AND
    longitude_deg LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' AND latitude_deg LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'
) AS temp
WHERE
  temp.Distance < 50000
Order BY
  temp.Distance
```

Comment: Well does 'empty values` are giving you hard time, add `ISNULL(latitude_deg , 0)` and like that to every other value you casting to numeric

Comment: i guess that a record with null in `latitude_deg` is not usefull, so you could either do `isnull()` on that column or maybe better to add it to your where clause so records with empty `latidude_Deg` are not fetched

Comment: Not fetching is better because `lat = 0`/`lon = 0` would be valid coordinated while the dataset is not valid. But I already tried to exclude them as seen in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this logic doesn't make sense:

```
WHERE isnumeric(longitude_deg) = 1 AND
      isnumeric(latitude_deg) = 1 AND
      longitude_deg LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' AND
      latitude_deg LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'
```

The `like` is looking for *non-numeric* characters.  I think you intend:

```
WHERE isnumeric(longitude_deg) = 1 AND
      isnumeric(latitude_deg) = 1 AND
      longitude_deg NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' AND
      latitude_deg NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'
```

This ensures that the values are numeric.

The solution to your problem -- at least in SQL Server 2012+ -- is to use `try_convert()` or `try_cast()`:

```
  (3956 * 2 * ASIN(
      SQRT(
          POWER(
              SIN((53.6349994 - abs(try_convert(numeric, latitude_deg))) * pi() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(53.6349994 * pi()/180) * COS(abs(try_convert(numeric, latitude_deg)) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((10.0117336 - try_convert(numeric, longitude_deg)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) AS Distance
```

This will prevent any conversion errors.

You shouldn't use just `numeric`.  Use either a floating point representation or something with decimal places, say `numeric(20, 10)`.

The reason this occurs with the `order by` is because of the SQL optimizer.  You clearly have some lat/long values that do not convert correctly to a `numeric`.  SQL Server allows itself to re-arrange operations, so the conversion might take place *before* the filtering by the `where` clause.  This is part of the overall query optimization.

Comment: If `try_convert()` or `try_cast()` were used inside select what is the value if convert/cast fails? That must not result in 0 because `lat = 0`/`lon = 0` would be valid coordinates while the dataset is not valid.

Comment: Okay, the solution turns to be less far than expected. I tried much until I came to `longitude_deg LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'` and then I gave up trying not knowing that I was almost close to what I wanted to have. I actually just forgot to negate the `LIKE` statement as you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: @shaedrich . . . They return `NULL`, so the whole expression will be `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So I guess, filtering is what I wanted.

Comment: @shaedrich . . . The query will still filter down to the rows that you want (using the `WHERE`).  This will just prevent the error.

Comment: I won't get back unwanted rows in result, will I?

Comment: @shaedrich . . . Your `WHERE` clause should still filter out the rows you want to filter out.

Comment: So that's what I want or did I miss something?